# bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones error, don't know how to fix

Tags: rigging, armature, 3d-printing

[image]
Hi, I am new to blender and this sub. I was trying to pose a model so I can 3d print later, adding a dress and hair later. I followed a quick tutorial by blender using rigify add on but when I parent my model to the bones I get bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones error. I tried some fixes such as decimate the vertices and cleaning up by duplicate vertices but nothing works. When I sculpted the model, I sculpted separate body parts and used a boolean modifier to combine them if that means anything.

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1EHq3Pg1pdTaOISIUr4A6vR2tiC7OQh3x

Comment: The mesh is very dense (~700k vertices). It's fine for printing I guess, but these many vertices will give you a hard time with the rig. Either consider a retopology or start over with a premade base mesh. You can reshape it in the sculpt mode to fit your existing high-poly sculpt. For printing, you can add a Multres (or Subdivision) modifier when the pose is final. Rigify's meta rig is only to lay out the bones. The character is controlled by the generated rig if you want to take fully advantage of Rigify.

Comment: I honestly don't understand I decimated to 34,400 vertices, I didn't know 700k was a lot but I still get the error bone heat weighting: failed. I can't parent to the bones at all when selecting the model first then shift clicking the bones to do the automatic weighting.

Comment: I decimated the vertices and did a remesh and was able to rig the model. I didn't know 700k was a lot of vertices so now its 30k and I needed to remesh to parent the bones with the model. Thank you